# Error 1064 with this SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT `news_posts`.`ID` , `category`.`ID` , `news_posts`.`Title` , `news_posts`.`Author` , `news_posts`.`Time` , `news_posts`.`Cat_ID` , `news_posts`.`Tags` , `news_posts`.`imageLocation` , `news_posts`.`thumbLocation` , `category`.`name`
FROM `news`.`category`
LEFT JOIN `category`.`ID` = `news_posts`.`Cat_ID`
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This is the error it brings

> *1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`Cat_ID` LIMIT 0, 30' at line 16*

Comment: I'd say its the '.Cat_ID LIMIT 0, 30' at line 16

Comment: just you would have check your left join syntax perfectly...! Show some research effort maan..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the table name `news_posts` and the `ON` keyword. It should be:

```
...
FROM `news`.`category`
LEFT JOIN news_posts ON `category`.`ID`  ...
...
```

Like so:

```
SELECT 
  `news_posts`.`ID` , `category`.`ID` , 
  `news_posts`.`Title` , `news_posts`.`Author` , 
  `news_posts`.`Time` , `news_posts`.`Cat_ID` , 
  `news_posts`.`Tags` , `news_posts`.`imageLocation` , 
  `news_posts`.`thumbLocation` , `category`.`name`
FROM `news`.`category`
LEFT JOIN news_posts ON `category`.`ID` = `news_posts`.`Cat_ID`
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: thank Mahmoud and Jodrell, Yes Mahmoud, you are right, i forgot exactly that.                                                             <code>SELECT `news_posts`.`ID` , `category`.`ID` , `news_posts`.`Title` , `news_posts`.`Author` , LEFT( `news_posts`.`Content` , 100 ) AS `Excerpt` , `news_posts`.`Content` , `news_posts`.`Time` , `news_posts`.`Cat_ID` , `news_posts`.`Tags` , `news_posts`.`imageLocation` , `news_posts`.`thumbLocation` , `category`.`name`
FROM `news`.`news_posts`
LEFT JOIN category ON `category`.`ID` = `news_posts`.`Cat_ID`
LIMIT 0 , 30</code>